# Can I require that a child initialize variables declared in its parent class?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class Animal, with classes that inherit variables from that class. For instance, a Name string will hold the name of the animal that class represents.

My question is, can I require that those variables be initialized in the child's constructor?  I want to ensure that Cat.cs, Dog.cs, etc actually store a name. I believe I can create a virtual Start() or Awake() method, but that will only assure that the Name string have *something* in it, but not the actual name of the animal.

Comment: Make the constructor of the base class take arguments and don't allow using the default constructor. Inherited classes can have a default constructor but will have to call the parameterized constructor of the base class.

Comment: @Ron Do you have an example?  Specifically, I don't know what you mean by not allowing the default constructor.  Or, that is, how to go about doing that.

Comment: What do you mean by `name of the animal`? If you mean you want it to contain `Dog` for `Dog.cs`, and `Cat` for `Cat.cs`, then don't use a string, but add a `AnimalType` enumeration, and require them to implement `public abstract AnimalType AnimalType { get; }` in the base class.

Comment: @RonBeyer You should post that as an answer, I think.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not *variables* that are inherited, it's *fields* and *properties*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'll add this constructor to the base `Animal` class:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    protected Animal(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Any type derives from it will be required to supply that argument to the constructor:

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This is almost exactly the same as haim770, but shows you can have default constructors as well (and one other thing I'll point out at the bottom)

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog()
        : base("Rover")
    {

    }

    public Dog(string name)
        : base(name)
    {

    }
}
```

The only other thing to note here is that the constructor of `Animal` is not declared `protected`. Why? Because it doesn't really matter. Because `Animal` is an abstract class you can't create new instances of it anyway, so making the constructor `public` is functionally equivalent to making it `protected` in this case.

Comment: +1, *Technically*, `public` is indeed equivalent in this case, but it's very common and more expressive to declare it as `protected`. See what ReSharper has to say: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Make+constructor+in+abstract+class+protected

Comment: Thank you!!  I wish you could choose two answers when both are excellent

Comment: I would accept @haim770 answer over mine too, just wanted to show an alternative.